# Swift: cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Void>'

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I do a bunch of work with `[Uint8]` arrays. But I often have to recast these as `NSData` objects to interface with iOS frameworks such as `CoreBluetooth`. So I have lots of code that might look something like:

```
var input:[UInt8] = [0x60, 0x0D, 0xF0, 0x0D]
let data = NSData(bytes: input, length: input.count)
```

Being tired of having to insert this extra `let data = ...` line, I thought I would just extend those arrays with a computed property to do the work. Then I could just do things like:

```
aBluetoothPeriperal.write(myBytes.nsdata, ...)
```

So it's basically just extension sugar. I can't extend Array, but I can extend a protocol:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == UInt8 {
    var nsdata:NSData {
        return NSData(bytes: self, length: self.count)
    }
}
```

Which produces an error that looks like:

```
Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:3:24: error: cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Void>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')
                return NSData(bytes: self, length: self.count)
                                 ^~~~
```

Sadly, the more I use Swift--and I really do like some things about Swift--the more I'm reminded of my negative experiences with trying to understand reams of unhelpful compiler output when I tried my hand at C++ with lots of generics and stuff years ago. So please Obi Wan, help me see the light here!

Comment: How do you plan on calling an extension like this? Can you add what the calling code would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSData(bytes:, length:)` takes an `UnsafePointer<Void>` as first parameter, and you cannot pass an arbitrary `SequenceType` here.

You *can* pass an `Array` which would be passed as the address of the
first array element. It is however not guaranteed that `Array` elements
are stored in contiguous memory.

Therefore:

- Define an `Array` extension instead of a `Sequence` extension.
- Use the `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` method to get a pointer
  to contiguous array storage.

Possible solution:

```
extension Array where Element : IntegerType {
    var nsdata : NSData {
        return self.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
            NSData(bytes: $0.baseAddress, length: self.count * strideof(Element))
        }
    }
}

let input:[UInt8] = [0x60, 0x0D, 0xF0, 0x0D]
print(input.nsdata) // <600df00d>
```

Swift does currently not allow to restrict an array extension 
to a concrete type:

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 { }
// error: same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic
```

therefore it is generalized to any elements conforming to `IntegerType`.

For a *sequence* you could then do a conversion to an array first:

```
let data = Array(myUInt8sequence).nsdata
```

Comment: OK, this works, but I have more questions than before! I thought one couldn't extend templated structs, but had to extend protocols with where refinements? But clearly, I was wrong about that? But then what confuses me is that you use `IntegerType` rather than `UInt8`? I tried UInt8, and it got mad because UInt8 was a type rather than a protocol.

Comment: Also, I didn't need to use the withUnsafeBufferPointer to make the compiler happy. What undesirable behavior would occur if I just skipped that wrapper and used the default NSData(bytes: self...)?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: As of Xcode 7 beta 2 you can extend restricted array types. But you can restrict the element type only to a protocol, not to a concrete type, that's why I chose IntegerType. – Lookup the online help of withUnsafeBufferPointer. It makes sure that the array elements are in contiguous storage, that is otherwise not guaranteed.

Comment: Does that mean I can extend other templated structs as well, as long as I stick to protocol types in the refinements? Or is it special for Array?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: Yes, you can. – It is not special for Array.

Comment: Ah yes, found this rather terse comment in the 7.0 release notes: "Public extensions of generic types are now permitted." And nothing else. I wonder why they limit it to Protocol types in the where clauses.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want.

```
protocol ByteOnly: IntegerType {}
extension UInt8: ByteOnly {}

extension Array where Element: ByteOnly {
    var n : NSData { return NSData(bytes: self, length: self.count) }
}
// does it work with UInt8
var input5:[UInt8] = [0x61, 0x0D, 0xF1, 0x0D]
let data5 = input5.n // YES

// does it work on ints?
var ints: [Int] = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
let idata5 = ints.n // no
```

Comment: Awesome addition. Thanks!